# Better method for limiting records based on certain criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried a few different queries for limiting the result set to what I need, but I keep missing something.

In my example, I have three document types: Registration, Title, and Voucher.  If an ASSET_ID has a record where DOC TYPE = Title but also has another record where DOC_TYPE = Voucher, then I don't want to display the Voucher line.  But if the ASSET_ID only has a Voucher line, then I want to display the record.  The third criteria is that if the same asset_id has two or more voucher lines, then I only want to display one.

Below is an example using fictitious data:

```
ASSET_ID    DOC_TYPE        State
101         Registration    TX
102         Title           AL
103         Title           NY
104         Title           CA
104         Voucher     
105         Title           CA
106         Voucher
106         Title           MD
107         Voucher
107         Voucher
```

I thought of two approaches.  My first thought was to write a query that removes the Voucher from the results altogether:

```
SELECT * FROM assets WHERE doc_type <> 'Voucher'
```

And then I was going to UNION another query that only pulls the Voucher doc_type:

```
SELECT asset_id, doc_type, state FROM assets WHERE doc_type <> 'Voucher'
UNION
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(asset_id), doc_type, state FROM assets WHERE 
doc_type = 'Voucher')
```

What I ended up doing was writing the union'ed query to reference the original query looking for values that meet a criteria NOT IN the first query.  But this feels like a horribly inefficient way to write the query:

```
SELECT asset_id, doc_type, state FROM assets WHERE doc_type <> 'Voucher'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT(asset_id), doc_type, state FROM assets WHERE doc_type = 
'Voucher' AND asset_id NOT IN (SELECT asset_id, doc_type, state FROM assets  
WHERE doc_type <> 'Voucher')
```

The above works, but I'm assuming there is a much cleaner way to handle this than what I am proposing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please notice that "DISTINCT" is not an operator you can apply to a single column of a query: it applies to the WHOLE ROW.   the (asset_id) is not a value you are passing to the DISCTINCT operator.... distinct is just an operator that eliminates duplicates of the whole row.... and also UNION actually does the same job. "Union" is actually a "union all" operator (which keeps duplicates) on wich is then applied the DISTINCT operator... actually you are doing DISTINCT twice in that query: first you do it on the second subquery, then you do it again on the "union all" of both queries

Comment: Thank you.  I did not know that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
SQL> with assets (asset_id, doc_type, state) as
  2    (select 101, 'registration', 'tx' from dual union all
  3     select 102, 'title'       , 'al' from dual union all
  4     select 103, 'title'       , 'ny' from dual union all
  5     select 104, 'title'       , 'ca' from dual union all
  6     select 104, 'voucher'     , null from dual union all
  7     select 105, 'title'       , 'ca' from dual union all
  8     select 106, 'voucher'     , null from dual union all
  9     select 106, 'title'       , 'md' from dual union all
 10     select 107, 'voucher'     , null from dual union all
 11     select 107, 'voucher'     , null from dual
 12    ),
 13  inter as
 14    (select asset_id, doc_type, state,
 15       row_number() over (partition by asset_id
 16                          order by decode(doc_type, 'title', 1, 'voucher', 2)) rn
 17     from assets
 18    )
 19  select asset_id, doc_type, state
 20  from inter
 21  where rn = 1
 22  order by asset_id;

  ASSET_ID DOC_TYPE     ST
---------- ------------ --
       101 registration tx
       102 title        al
       103 title        ny
       104 title        ca
       105 title        ca
       106 title        md
       107 voucher

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Partition By did the trick.  I tried it previously, but now I see where the ordering affects the row count which affects the way we can filter the data.